# Dynamic memory allocation code

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning the basics of memory allocation in C(C++).

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
void main(){

    char *str;
    char *input;
    int *ilist;
    int i, size1, size2;

    printf("Number of letters in word: ");
    scanf("%d", &size1);
    printf("Number of integers: ");
    scanf("%d", &size2);                  

    str = (char *)malloc(size1*sizeof(char) + 1); 

    ilist = (int *)malloc(size2*sizeof(int)); 
    if (str == NULL || ilist == NULL){ 
        printf("Lack of memory");
    }
    printf("Word: ");
    int k = size1;
    // the following line is done to prevent memory bugs when the amount of 
    letters in greater than size1.
    scanf("%ks", &str); //I guess something is wrong with this line
    /* user inputs a string */
    for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        printf("Number %d of %d: ", i + 1, size2);
        //this scanf is skipped during the execution of the program
        scanf("%d", ilist + i);         
    }


    free(str);
    free(ilist);
    system("pause");

}
```

The program asks user to write the amount of letters in the word and the amount of digits in the number. Then user writes the word. Then he writes integer one-by-one depending on what number was typed before. The problem I have is when the user writes the whole word, next scanf is skipped. 
Thank you. 
P.S. can there be other  kind of memory bugs in this code?

Comment: It's a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: First lesson c != c++ and in c you don't cast `malloc()` to the target pointer type because you don't need to.

Comment: I suggest installing Valgrind http://valgrind.org/ to check for memory leaks.

Comment: Why are "stdio.h" in quotation marks instead of brackets? It should be `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include "stdio.h"`.

Comment: `scanf("%ks", &str);` doesn't do what you think it does. It tells `scanf` to scan a `%`,a `k` and a `s` and not to scan a string of maximum length `k`.

Comment: @ilent2 - That is my job to type that in :-)  - anyway why think that the users are that good to input the correct values for the size of wiords and the length of the list?

Comment: @CoolGuy how can I do so that it scans till the length of str?

Comment: All that comes to my mind is `int c, counter = 0; while(counter < size1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) str[counter++] = c; str[counter] = '\0';`

Comment: `scanf("%99s", str)` to read a string of up to 99 characters, the array needs to accommodate the null character - i.e. be 100 characters long

Comment: OT: `main()` returns `int` not `void`.

Comment: @alk - In C void is OK

Comment: @EdHeal; No. From C99, return type should be `int`.

Comment: It still works for historical reasons - https://ideone.com/c0yBkK

Comment: @EdHeal: For a hosted env/ it's UB as per the C11 Standard appendix J2 along with 5.1.2.2.1.

Comment: use fgets then sscanf and your troubles will disappear

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *//I guess something is wrong with this line*...
The format specifier `"%ks"` in `scanf("%ks", &str);`  contains a k, which is not a valid *[scanf() format specifier](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)*.

Excerpt from link:
[image]

For user input value in the `width` specifier, you can create a format buffer:

```
char format[10];
int k = size1;//assume size1 == 10
sprintf(format, "%c%d%c", '%', k, 's');
//assuming k == 10, format contains "%10s"
scanf(format, &str); //now, there is nothing wrong with this line
```

*Other Observations*
There are *[several recommended prototypes for the C main function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020691/645128)*.  `void main()` is not one of them.

***This line***: `str = (char *)malloc(size1*sizeof(char) + 1);`
Could be written as:

```
str = malloc(size1 + 1); //removed sizeof(char) as it is always 1
                         //removed cast, not recommended in C
```

***Similar for*** for: `ilist = (int *)malloc(size2*sizeof(int));`

```
ilist = malloc(size2*sizeof(int));//remove cast, but keep sizeof(int) 
                                  //unlike sizeof(char), sizeof(int) is never 1
```

A few *Basics* to consider for dynamic memory allocation in C:

1) In C, do not cast the output of *[calloc(), malloc() or realloc()](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~saul/parasite/man/man3/malloc.3.html)*.  (do however cast in C++.)
2) For each call to *calloc(), malloc() or realloc()*, there must be a corresponding call to *[free()](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~saul/parasite/man/man3/malloc.3.html)*
3) While automatic memory is sourced from the *[stack](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)*, dynamic memory comes from the *[heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html_)*
4) If *[speed efficiency is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291991/heap-vs-stack-in-regard-to-read-write-speed)*, favor the stack over the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `scanf` use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). But, you need to clear the input buffer first to consume the `\n` left behind by previous `scanf`s.

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // Clear input buffer  
fgets(str, k, stdin);
```

Note that if a `'\n'` is read then it will be stored in `str`. You should have to take care of that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch; Not a standard C library function.

Comment: @haccks: But it's POSIX.